# Ajax call returning a partial view or a json

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax call to an action in a controller:

```
            $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetSchool", "Controller")",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "text",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data.length < 14){
                            $('form').submit();
                        } else {
                            *some action*
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, statusText, errorText) {
                        alert('Error: ' + errorText)
                    }
                });
```

The GetSchool is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult GetSchool(SchoolModel school)
    {
        //search the db for school
        if (school found)
        {
            return PartialView("partial", school);
        } else
            return Json(new { data = "KO" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Basically the requirement is as follows :

 in case there is a school in the database, then display school in partial view.  Else submit the form doing the ajax call.
Right now I am validating this condition based on the data.length,  but I now this is not the right way to do.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You could just use `return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and then in the callback, `if (data) { // some action } else { $('form').submit(); }`

Comment: Create method to check whether school exists in database or not (returns `bool`), then in JS code, check if exists - display school, if not - submit the form.

Comment: try not to use multiple return types on the same method it will make complex problems, you can just do same as above mentioned comments by others

Comment: You need to change your design. Having a single method that returns two different things may not be correct.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Can you post this as answer pls?

Comment: I can, but your requirement seems a bit odd - what is triggering your ajax call, and what is the purpose of displaying the partial (there might be a better way to approach it)